# Execute ajax call right after all fields are filled

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I need to check all the fields first:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#loginform").submit(function(){
```

LIKE:

```
        //CHECK INPUT
        $('#loginform :input:not(:button)').each(function(n,element){  
            if ($(element).val()=='') {
                $(".message").css('margin-top', '13px').html('<p>O campo '+element.id+' tem de ter um valor!</p>').fadeIn("slow").delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);
                return false;  
            }
        });
```

AND MAKE AJAX CALL AFTER ALL FIELDS ARE FILLED:

```
    //AJAX CALL
         $.post(...
         BLÁ BLÁ

    return false;
```

How can I submit values after check all fields?
Thank you as always.

UPDATE:

The solution "I found".

First validate in client side.
Second validate server side.

With the first measure several ajax call's are prevented before all fields are ok!
With the second "move" we prevent malicious intentions.

Thank you very much.
I been learning so much with you :)

Comment: I may not understand what your asking but all you really need to do is write a method that checks if all fields are filled. If they are, then go to another method that makes a AJAX call

Comment: Yes that's what I need... how can I achieve that using jquery?

Comment: Beware that you may perplex and annoy your users by doing this. Users expect to click a submit button, and may need to review the form information before they do so. If you sweep the rug out from under them (so to speak), the data may be incomplete or inaccurate. The normal process is to validate the form when the user submits it, showing errors if any fields are incomplete.

Comment: yes I do understand but I want to save some server side power making this to run in client side... what do you think of it?

Comment: @FCC-PT: Client-side validation is still an option. There are several jQuery libraries that will provide this functionality (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation). You can simply mark all fields as required, and the validation will happen before the form is submitted to the server.

Comment: Make the validation run ONLY client side?  Bad idea!  Anyone can submit (POST) something to your server without ever seeing your form page or the javascript it contains.

Comment: @James: You are correct, of course. We are dealing with the issue of whether to submit the form automatically, so none of these comments should be misconstrued to lessen the need for server-side validation.

Comment: OK - removing server validation was the only potential "server side power saving" I could spot in the code hence the cause for concern.

Comment: Ok so the best thing to do is to check every field with php using ajax?

Comment: @FCC-PT: No. You should use jQuery to validate that all of the fields are filled out when the user clicks submit. If they are not filled out, display a message near the empty fields instructing the user to complete it. If they are all filled out, submit the form to your server, validate the data using PHP, and process the data as needed.

Comment: That is the right procedure :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what your looking for?

```
    var callAjax = true;

    //CHECK INPUT
    $('#loginform :input:not(:button)').each(function(n,element){  
        if ($(element).val()=='') {
            //Code then set bool
            callAjax = false;  
        }
    });

    if(callAjax){
    $.ajax( {
        url: "form action",
        type: "POST",
        data: $("#loginForm").serialize(),
    ....
    }
```

Comment: For this to work, you'd need to call this everytime a value changes (listen to the change event on each field). The way it is, it only checks once

Comment: shouldn't be var callAjax = true ?!?

Comment: Yea, I forgot it was Javascript. Good call

Answer (score 0):

If you mean whats the easiest way to get the form data into you ajax request?
use the .serialize() method on your form like:

```
$.ajax( {
    url: "form action",
    type: "POST",
    data: $("#loginForm").serialize(),
....
```

Comment: I know how to submit ajax and it's working perfect... but I just want to submit ajax values after ALL input are filled.

Comment: Please don't use a setInterval, that should always be your last approach, very inefficient. Just listen to the change event for each field

Answer (score 0):

```
// Add these to your onReady code
function checkFields() {
  var filledIn = true;
  $('#loginform :input:not(:button)').each(function(n,element){  
      if ($(element).val()=='') {
        filledIn = false;
        return false; // stop loop execution
     }
  });
  return filledIn;
}


$('#loginform :input:not(:button)').change(function() {
  if (checkFields()) {
    $.ajax( {
      url: "form action",
      type: "POST",
      data: $("#loginForm").serialize(),
      ....
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: I just read that you want to use this to actually submit the form. I would suggest against that. Let the user decide when to submit it. A good use for this would be to run some server side validation that can't be done on the client so the user doesn't have to wait to see that they have entered some invalid data.